# QGIS 2.14.3 can't attach oracle spatial table

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial, qgis-2.14

when I try to attach spatial table in QGIS, the application close without errors.
The tables which have problem have a UUID column:

```
  mslink    NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL,
  uuid      RAW(16)       DEFAULT sys_guid() NOT NULL,..
```

How I can open this table with QGIS ?

Comment: Is the table created by MicroStation?

Comment: This table is created for Microstation, but it was created in SQL. This table don't have a primary key because Microstation.

Comment: I would try by creating a view for skipping the uuid field.

Comment: The view with UUID is OK. I think that the problem becomes sys_guid () not null... Or because there are 2 fields "not null"?